# `MissingAttributeError` when trying to save after a `select`

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

This works on rails 3.2:

```
replies = Reply.select([:id, :reply]).limit 30
replies.first.account # nil
replies.first.account = Account.first
replies.first.save #this works, it updates account on db even when was not included in select
```

But when i tried to do that on rails 4 I receive:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError:
```

Is not possible to save a attribute if I don't retrieve it using `select`?

Comment: I take it that a Reply has_one Account?

Answer (score 0):

From the [guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields):

"Be careful because this also means you're initializing a model object with only the fields that you've selected. If you attempt to access a field that is not in the initialized record you'll receive: ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: "

So you are probably referencing the missing attribute in either a validation or a callback.

Eg: if you have an attribute named 'title' on your Reply model with a presence validation, then when you try to save your reply which is initialized to:

```
#<Reply id: 1, reply: "reply">
```

you will receive a MissingAttributeError for title because it is not part of your initialized object.

Comment: Is there any way around that? I only want to validate if the attribute has been included in the `select`